# Global Variable Lifespan in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I'm in the process of learning React (and Javascript) and working on a data model is part of my self-imposed tutelage. On my first attempt I created a basic javascript object that would be used with a getter and a setter as follows:

**story_store.js**

```
var story = {
  id:"",
  title:""
}

module.exports = {
    getStory: function() {
        return story
    }

    setStory: function(id, title) {
        story.id = id;
        story.title = title;
    }
}
```

I'd then set the object during a network call and would be able to access (get) it until the application terminated. This version worked as expected.

For the next version I placed my model and  getters/setters in separate files and used an array to store the model objects.

**story_model.js**

```
export function Story(id, title, text='') {
    let story = {}
    story.id = id;
    story.title = title;
    story.text = text;

    return story
}
```

**story_store.js**

```
var stories = [];

module.exports = {
    getStory: function(id) {
        return stories.find(x => x.id === id);
    },
    setStories: function(stories) {
        stories.forEach(function(story) {
            stories.push(story);
        });
    }
}
```

This time the setter worked as expected however when I tried to access the array later on in execution it was empty. I'm guessing the issue has to do with the way I'm creating the objects before I put them in an array but that seems strange to me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the setter sets the value of the parameter `stories` - JavaScript works from the inside out to find a variable, and as soon as it finds one it stops. You need to change your parameter name in `setStories` to make it look for the global `stories` array:

```
setStories: function(storyArray) {
    storyArray.forEach(function(story) {
        stories.push(story);
    });
}
```

Also note that you can use `concat` to do the exact same thing:

```
setStories: function(storyArray) {
    stories.concat(storyArray);
}
```

Comment: I really thought I was going to learn something but it was just a dumb mistake. Thanks!